# How to reset Telegram unread message counter in KDE panel?

Tags: kde, telegram

After having read my telegram messages in Telegram Desktop (installed from the installer on the application's website) running on Kubuntu 18.04, the counter does not refresh until the application is closed and reopened. Has anyone else noted this bahavior? Any workarounds?

---

[image]

Comment: Do you have muted chats on Telegram? Sometimes if the group's admin pins the message even if you muted notifications for that group it will be shown in telegram icon counter until you check that pinned message.

Comment: @JoKer Interesting, indeed I have. I haven't checked yet that the behavior is limited to such cases.

Comment: @JoKeR You can add this as an answer, it seems to have been the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have muted chats on Telegram sometimes if the group's admin pins the message or a photo in a group even if you muted notifications for that group it will be shown in Telegram icon counter until you check that pinned message.

That is just standard behavior of Telegram so you won't miss any urgent or special notification update in a group or chat. It also might occur if somebody marks "@yournickname" in a chat.